# Refer library via IFS when program running on iASP in IBM i

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-ifs

I have a CL program which is referring to a library via IFS like

```
/QSYS.LIB/<libname>.LIB/<filename>.FILE
```

Currently this program is running on *SYSBAS, where everything runs fine. I want to know when this program will be executing on iASP, then will it run to any sort of problem or not?

I have two situations:

- When library it is referring to is on the *SYSBAS.
- When library it is referring to is on the iASP itself.

I want my program to run fine in both the situations.

Answer (score 1):

[Recommended practice](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaly/rzalystructure.htm) when dealing with iASP, is to have user programs & data in the iASP.

Basically, an iASP is designed to keep multiple DB's separate.  You can have stuff work cross iASP's, but it's extra work.

See also, [Application considerations for independent disk pools](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaly/rzalyapplications.htm)

Answer (score 0):

*SYSBAS = /QSYS.LIB/.LIB/.FILE
IASP01 = /iasp01/QSYS.LIB/.LIB/.FILE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).